# Give Wget priority for my internet bandwidth

Tags: networking, wget, bandwidth

Is there any way for me to configure something so that no matter what other apps and machines are using my internet bandwidth, Wget will always get first priority?

(So that even if I'm streaming lots of videos and such on other machines on my network, Wget's download speed will be limited only by the remote host and my internet connection)

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 0):

Since wget isn't in windows, I'll draw my card for how to do it under ubuntu linux:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/165577/how-do-i-reserve-bandwidth

Comment: wget does exit for Windows but agree safe assumption the user is using Linux

Comment: Yeah, I expressed myself badly; I've got wget installed on windows right now since it's such a great program. There's a lot of tools lacking by default.